# Scala dynamic typing, type bounds and java objects - is this expected behavior or a bug?

Tags: scala-2.8

Sorry if this has been covered already. The following simple example of dynamic typing and type bounds does not work with a list of strings but works perfectly well with a (scala) class containing a defined length() function. Is this expected behavior or a bug? If it is expected behavior, is there a way to define the type bound such that it would work for a List of String objects as well as a list of arbitrary scala objects with a length(0 function?

```
def sumlen[T <: {def length : Int}](l : List[T]) : Int = {
     def sl(l : List[T], acc : Int) : Int = l match {
         case Nil => acc
         case h::t => sl(t, h.length + acc)
     }
     sl(l, 0)
}

val l1 = List("This", "is", "a", "test")

sumlen(l1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
def sumlen[T <: {def length() : Int}](l : List[T]) : Int = {
//                         ^^
```

And yes, it is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the solution. Just curious as to the reasoning behind this particular "feature". It seems inconsistent with the rest of the syntax and artificially differentiates between scala-native and java classes.

Comment: @user693384: the feature is that `def foo()` is different from `def foo`. Typically if you use the corrected version with `sumlen(List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6),List(7),List(8)))`, it won't work as `def length()` and `def length` are different and this difference is a feature. You have to make two version. If there is a bug somewhere, it is that `length()` on `String` takes an empty list of parameters and should more be parameterless as it is side effect free.